# Como posicionar uma imagem com vertical-align?

Tags: html, css

Tenho um menu em que posiona a logomarca do site da seguinte forma:

**html:**

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="layout/img/logo.png" class="logo" />
</a>
```

**css:**

```
header div a img.logo{
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

Porem, essa forma de posiciona-la não funciona corretamente em todos os navegadores, e antes de eu decidir usar esse método de posicionamento, eu queria posicionar usando `vertical-align`. É possível?

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias formas de fazer isso. Mas se é que eu entendi você quer fazer um **vertical-align** *middle*. Okay ?

Para usar o **vertical-align** independente do seu valor, deve-se usar a propriedade **table**, **table-cell**. Elas se relacionam.

Mas o que você pode fazer para facilitar é definir um **line-height** no seu HEADER.

Ficando assim:

```
<header>
<a href="#">
    <img src="logo.png" />
</a>
</header>


header{
    line-height: 120px;
}
```

Automaticamente a imagem ficará no meio.

Comment: Gostei do seu método, testei aqui e deu certo, mas... tem um probleminha a tag <a> ficou alinhada bem ao meio, mas a tag <img> com a logomarca não ficou no meio, tentei resolver mudando os display's para outros, mas não deu certo. :( sabe como resolvo? [link] (http://i.imgur.com/eJKz3Vx.png) , aqui está o codigo no JSFiddle: [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/gerlandoprado/jmb17zwe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Como o Diego disse a única maneira de trabalhar com o vertical-align é usando table e table-cell. Caso você queira mesmo utilizar, tente fazer dessa forma.

```
<header>
    <a href="#" id="conteudo">
        <img src="layout/img/logo.png" class="logo" />
    </a>
</header>

html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table
}

#conteudo {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```